# Aur package Showing Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, packaging, archlinux

I'm making an AUR package for arch linux and i have made the PKGBUILD file with reference through various YouTube videos and Blog post and Official AUR packaging documentation all I want is to move the python scripts to the /usr/bin/ directory but its throwing error of permission denied.

**This is my PKGBUILD file for AUR package**

```
# Maintainer: Ashwini Sahu <ashwinisahu990@gmail.com>

_pkgname=hbhc
pkgname=${_pkgname}-git
pkgver=r15.e5f7975
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="A fast and Open Source Home Baked Hash Cracker for linux Written in Python3"
arch=('any')
url="https://github.com/ASHWIN990/${_pkgname}/sssssssss"
license=('GPL3')
depends=(python3)
makedepends=(git)
source=("git://github.com/ASHWIN990/hbhc.git")
md5sums=('SKIP')

pkgver() {
        cd "$_pkgname"
        printf "r%s.%s" "$(git rev-list --count HEAD)" "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"
}

package() {
        cd "$_pkgname"
        install -m 644 ".man/hbhc.1.gz" "/usr/local/share/man/man1/"
        cp sha* /usr/bin/ | echo -e "MOVING THE PYTHON SCRIPTS IN /usr/bin"
        cp md5* /usr/bin/
        cp hbhc /usr/bin/
        cp .man/hbhc.1.gz /usr/local/share/man/man1/hbhc.1.gz
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting while making the package:

```
┌─[ashwinisahu@ashwini-main]─[~/Other/build]
└──╼ $makepkg
==> Making package: hbhc-git r15.e5f7975-1 (Friday 22 May 2020 01:45:52 AM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Cloning hbhc git repo...
Cloning into bare repository '/home/ashwinisahu/Other/build/hbhc'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 68, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (68/68), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Total 68 (delta 37), reused 49 (delta 28), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (68/68), 15.20 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (37/37), done.
==> Validating source files with md5sums...
    hbhc ... Skipped
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Creating working copy of hbhc git repo...
Cloning into 'hbhc'...
done.
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
==> Starting package()...
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/share/man/man1/hbhc.1.gz': Permission denied
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
    Aborting...
```

My new PKGBUILD file looks like this and it runs without any error:

```
# Maintainer: Ashwini Sahu <ashwinisahu990@gmail.com>

_pkgname=hbhc
pkgname=${_pkgname}-git
pkgver=r17.82d9453
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="A fast and Open Source Home Baked Hash Cracker for linux Written in Python3"
arch=('any')
url="https://github.com/ASHWIN990/${_pkgname}"
license=('GPL3')
depends=('python3')
makedepends=('git')
provides=('hbhc')
source=("git+https://github.com/ASHWIN990/hbhc.git")
md5sums=('SKIP')

pkgver() {
    cd "$_pkgname"
    printf "r%s.%s" "$(git rev-list --count HEAD)" "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"
}

package() {
    cd "$srcdir/${_pkgname}"
        install -Dm775 sha* -t ${pkgdir}/usr/bin/ | echo -e "MOVING THE PYTHON SCRIPTS IN /usr/bin"
        install -Dm775 md5* -t ${pkgdir}/usr/bin/
        install -Dm775 hbhc -t ${pkgdir}/usr/bin/
    install -Dm644 ${PWD}/.man/hbhc.1.gz -t ${pkgdir}/usr/share/man/man1/

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Just a heads up, I dont use Arch and I have never written a PKGBUILD for it. I am Fedora guy, but a similar error has bitten me there often enough.)

```
package() {
        cd "$_pkgname"
        install -m 644 ".man/hbhc.1.gz" "/usr/local/share/man/man1/"
        cp sha* /usr/bin/ | echo -e "MOVING THE PYTHON SCRIPTS IN /usr/bin"
        cp md5* /usr/bin/
        cp hbhc /usr/bin/
        cp .man/hbhc.1.gz /usr/local/share/man/man1/hbhc.1.gz
}
```

This code is executed when you are *building* the package, not when you are *installing* it. This is not running as a root user, but as the package-build user (I am not sure what that is, on Arch). As a non-root user, you are trying to copy your package to paths (like `/usr/...`) which only root can write to. That's not allowed and leads to the permission issue:

```
==> Starting package()...
install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/share/man/man1/hbhc.1.gz': Permission denied
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
```

But you dont want to run as root either. What you need to do is to install to the special location `$pkgdir`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_packages#Defining_PKGBUILD_variables. This special location looks like `/`, but you can write to it. Everything in `$pkgdir` becomes a part of the package you are building. Then, when you install the package you have just built, everything from `$pkgdir` is copied over to `/`.

In other words, when building a package, you install things to `$pkgdir/usr/bin/foo`. When that package is installed, that file gets placed at `/usr/bin/foo`.

```
package() {
        cd "$_pkgname"
        install -m 644 ".man/hbhc.1.gz" "$pkgdir/usr/local/share/man/man1/"
        cp sha* "$pkgdir/usr/bin/"
        cp md5* "$pkgdir/usr/bin/"
        cp hbhc "$pkgdir/usr/bin/"
        cp .man/hbhc.1.gz "$pkgdir/usr/local/share/man/man1/hbhc.1.gz"
}
```

This idea is also known as `DESTDIR` which is commonly documented in various `make` and similar tools:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html
- https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html

Hopefully that fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Where should I define this special variable: `$pkgdir`? `/usr/share/pacman/PKGBUILD`? Or `/etc/makepkg.conf`?

Comment: You shouldn't define it. As the Arch wiki says: "makepkg defines two variables that you should use". You can use `$pkgdir` without defining it yourself in the context of `makepkg`.